# Trouble in Cut a portion of an audio file, and add fade in and fadeout Effect

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

```
ffmpeg -i track1.wav -ss 00:00:38.160 -t 00:00:20.720 -vn -codec:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 256k -map a -af afade=t=in:ss=38:d=3,afade=t=out:st=55:d=3 output.mp3
```

This is how I am cutting the audio file.
My problem is, Fade in not working and fadeout working very well.
                   But if I cut audio from the beginning (0:0), Fade in and fade out working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is wrong, use this one: `ffmpeg -i track1.wav -ss 00:00:38.160 -t 00:00:20.720 -vn -codec:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 256k -map a -af afade=t=in:st=38:d=3,afade=t=out:st=55:d=3 output.mp3`

Comment: I had read you answer 3 times to see the one letter of the difference. It would by nice to include it in your answer, and explain the reason for it.